# Spring Boot 3 Upgrade - Autoconfiguration.imports ignored

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am upgrading an application from Spring Boot 2.6 to 3.1. The application is a modular gradle project and makes use of Spring's autoconfiguration.

There is an application that has dependencies to several modules, all these modules provide their own autoconfiguration via a `META-INF/spring.factories` class. They point to a configuration class that will initialize the code from that module and setup a respective component scan.

That's been working quite well in Spring Boot 2. As the Update Manual suggests, I have migrated these files to `META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports` and inserted the individual configurations one per line. The Configuration Class itself is annotated as `AutoConfiguration` and the Main class has `@ImportAutoConfiguration`.

However, when I start the application, the Autoconfiguration does not seem to be picked up and I get startup errors about missing beans. I verified 10 times that it's the right filename and referencing to the right classes.

Example cases:

main method in an admin-panel module:

```java
package de.herakles.platform.krakenadminpanel;

// import

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebMvc
@ImportAutoConfiguration
public class KrakenAdminPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KrakenAdminPanel.class, args);
    }

}
```

there's a gradle dependency on a module called *platform-dialect* which contains a bean of type `SupplierService`.

in the module platform-dialect I have this file: `platform-dialect/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring /org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports`

containing exactly this line:

```
de.herakles.platform.kraken.platformdialect.KrakenPlatformDialectConfiguration
```

and the configuration class looks like this:

```java
package de.herakles.platform.kraken.platformdialect;

//imports 

@AutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "de.herakles")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "de.herakles")
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KrakenPlatformDialectConfiguration.class)
public class KrakenPlatformDialectConfiguration {

}
```

In that module, there's a `de.herakles.platform.kraken.platformdialect.supplier.SupplierService` that is annotated as @Service and should be picked up by the component scan (it did prior to the upgrade).
However the error message I am getting is:

*Parameter 0 of constructor in de.herakles.platform.krakenadminpanel.dataengineering.VariantController required a bean of type 'de.herakles.platform.kraken.platformdialect.supplier.SupplierService' that could not be found.*

I am really struggling - tried all suggestions I could find with nothing working. I am also lacking any indication for how to debug the problem further as the documentation and information on the new autoconfiguration system is not very dense. Therefore I would be very thankful for a solution or a hint for how to debug this issue.

Thanks
Matthias

Comment: Since you tell the Spring Boot with @ComponentScan to look for the configuration class, why dont you define the SupplierService bean in this configuration and see if it will be caught by Spring Boot?

Comment: Is that whitespace in the name a typo or is that really there? I also don't see why you would need the `@ImportAutoConfiguration`. And have you made sure that that file is actually copied to the jar that you are including? Looks like it is missing.

Comment: adding a bean factory method to the configuration does not change a thing - it does not get called. 

For the whitespace, which one do you mean? I can confirm that the jar this depends on is present - as there's no ClassNotFound or NoClassDef Errors that would indicate a missing jar on the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

The Issue was in the Gradle Build:
Although the individual jars contained the new AutoConfiguration.imports file, these jars were not put in the uber jar created by the spring boot plugin - there were still old versions in there without the AutoConfiguration.imports.

Cleaning all build folders solved the problem.